# How to tag multiple people in facebook post (facebook api php)

Tags: php, facebook, yii

Hello this is my code and i have an array where i have all the id's of the users that i need to tag, how do i tag all of them, i'm using Yii framework, thanks in advance

```
public function actionSendD(){

    $response = $facebook->api()->api("/me/feed", "post", 
        array(
            'message' => "hello, somebody has sent you a gift in our paget",
            'picture' => CController::createAbsoluteUrl( str_replace("index.php/", "", Yii::app() -> theme -> baseUrl) .'/img/logo.png'),
            'link' => "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com",
            'name' => "gift",
            'caption' => "enjoy",
            'place' => "452157938259984",                   

            ));

    $this->redirect(array('Gift/index'));


}
```

Comment: You are aware that you are not allowed to prefill the message?

Comment: The text in the message parameter the user have to type them self. Every single character.

Comment: i just can't tag the people and just that? I just need to tag the users in a single post, i have the array, is that possible?

Comment: I didn't say anything about tagging people. I just wanted to warn you that the message field the user need to type themself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

I am adding `tags` in your array which have comma separated friends ids.

```
public function actionSendD(){

    $response = $facebook->api()->api("/me/feed", "post", 
        array(
            'message' => "hello, somebody has sent you a gift in our paget",
            'picture' => CController::createAbsoluteUrl( str_replace("index.php/", "", Yii::app() -> theme -> baseUrl) .'/img/logo.png'),
            'tags' => '1234567890123,123456767890321',  // comma separated friends ID's
            'link' => "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com",
            'name' => "gift",
            'caption' => "enjoy",
            'place' => "452157938259984"                

        ));

    $this->redirect(array('Gift/index'));

}
```

Comment: hmmm, and how i do it with and array $_SESSION['ids'] ??

Comment: @user3215218 just add this code in the tag array, `'tags' => implode(",", $_SESSION['ids']),`. thats all. If you say, I will update the above code.

Comment: @user3215218 The code works for you now? If Yes, please accept the solution. Other users (Who are searching for the solution) can take help from this. Thanks.

Comment: i can't because i need 15 of reputation :/